# How to sort array of string and int values, multiple attributes with alphabetical and "reversed"-alphabetical order

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I have an array containing `[name, surname, int1, int2]` elements and I need to sort it by this order:

- By `int1` (decreasing).
- If `int1` is the same, sort by `name` in "reversed"-alphabetical order.
- If `name` is the same, order by `surname` in alphabetical order.

So I have this:

```
print(sorted(a, key = lambda x: [-int(x[2]), x[0], x[1]]))
```

And I have no idea how to sort `x[0]` in reverse-alphabetical order
`-x[0], x[0][::-1]` doesn't work for me.

Example:

```
[('Petia', 'Anja', 3, 0),
 ('Vasia', 'Katia', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Katia', 3, 0),
 ('Kolia', 'Alexey', 10, 0),
 ('Yana', 'Anja', 10, 0)]
```

to

```
[('Yana', 'Anja', 10, 0),
 ('Kolia', 'Alexey', 10, 0),
 ('Vasia', 'Katia', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Anja', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Katia', 3, 0)]
```

Comment: Do you mean reversed alphabetical, as in z->a, or reversed, alphabetical, as in alphabetical on a reversed string?

Comment: @user3483203 z->a yeah. I added some example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a class with an implementation for `<` (`<` is all CPythons `sorted` requires - if you're using another Python implementation you might need additional comparison operators). That allows full control over the "ordering". For example:

```
class Sorter(object):
    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.name, self.surname, self.int1, self.int2 = tup
    def __lt__(self, other):
        # Just to make the logic clearer, in practise you could do nest the ifs
        # to avoid computing self.int1 == other.int1 twice
        if self.int1 == other.int1 and self.name == other.name:
            return self.surname < other.surname
        elif self.int1 == other.int1:
            return self.name > other.name
        else:
            return self.int1 > other.int1
```

Then use that as `key` for `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=Sorter)
[('Yana', 'Anja', 10, 0),
 ('Kolia', 'Alexey', 10, 0),
 ('Vasia', 'Katia', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Anja', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Katia', 3, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> intab='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> tab = string.maketrans(intab+intab.upper(), intab[::-1]+intab.upper()[::-1])
>>> 
>>> slst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: [-int(x[2]), x[0].translate(tab), x[1]])
>>> pprint(slst)
[('Yana', 'Anja', 10, 0),
 ('Kolia', 'Alexey', 10, 0),
 ('Vasia', 'Katia', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Anja', 3, 0),
 ('Petia', 'Katia', 3, 0)]
>>>
```